# Looking for a Hadith, the Prophets have the greatest Burden

Tags: source-identification

I am looking for a Hadith in which it says that the Prophets have the greatest burden, then the ones most like them, then the ones most like them.

Answer (score 7):

The Hadith can be found in Ibn Maja, Darimi etc. for example it is the Hadith # 1562 in Tirmidhi:

> When the Prophet May Allah's peace and praise be on him was asked
>   which people suffered the greatest affliction, he replied, "The
>   prophets, then those who come next to them, then those who come next
>   to them. A man is afflicted in keeping his religion. If he is firm in
>   his religion his trial is severe, but if there is weakness in his
>   religion it is made light for him, and it continues like that till he
>   walks on the earth having no sin."

See [here](http://dailyhadith.adaptivesolutionsinc.com/hadith/Most-Severely-Tried.htm), [here](http://islamicvoice.com/september.97/hadi.htm) and [here](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=86224).